# Como "quebrar" uma string em C puro para atribuir as partes a outras variáveis?

Tags: c, string

Tô fazendo um lance pra faculdade e estou perdido pra usar C pq aprendi a programar em Python.
É uma pergunta simples:
Se eu tenho uma string str, como posso fazer para "quebrá-la" em outras 3 para atribuir a três variáveis diferentes?

Exemplo:

```
str[ ] = "Bom dia pessoal"; 

str1[ ] = "Bom";  
str2[ ] = "dia"; 
str3[ ] = "pessoal"
```

Tentei usar o strtok(), mas apenas consegui usá-lo para imprimir as strings separadas no terminal, não cosegui armazenar as partes em outras variáveis. A alma caridosa que for me ajudar deverá ter em mente que, como sou um filho do Python, não domino 100% de ponteiros.

Comment: Quantos porcento você diria que entende de ponteiros?

Comment: 50%. Entendi a coisa de lidar com memória, ma tudo muito teórico. Tentei escrever uma função que fizesse essa separação, mas não consigo pensar em um modo de dar return numa string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem montes de maneiras de "quebrar" uma string em C, mais robustas, menos robustas, com ou sem alocação dinâmica, mas vou pegar exatamente no que disse:

> Tentei usar o `strtok()`, mas apenas consegui usá-lo para imprimir as strings separadas no terminal

Também dá para fazer com `strtok` e até é mais simples pois parte do trabalho já está feito.

### Quebra - Split com array alocado em *Stack*

Utilizando um array bidimensional em stack consegue fazer o split de alterando ligeiramente o [exemplo da documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int qtd_espacos(char *str){
    int espacos = 0;
    while(*str){
        if (*str == ' '){
           espacos++;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return espacos;
}

int main () {
    char str[] = "Bom dia pessoal";

    //quebrar - split da string
    int qtd_strings = qtd_espacos(str) + 1, i = 0;
    char strings[qtd_strings][strlen(str)];
    char *pch = strtok (str," ");
    while (pch != NULL){
        strcpy(strings[i++], pch); //copiar cada string para a posição correta
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    //mostrar cada uma
    for (i = 0;i < qtd_strings;++i){
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    } 

    //ou seguindo o seu exemplo
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/bun1sz)

Essencialmente a unica coisa que fiz a mais em relação à documentação, é a copia de cada string para o local certo através do [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/).

Para poder pré alocar o espaço certo para as strings contei quantos espaços existem para saber quantas strings serão criadas. Na verdade a quantidade de espaços + 1 pode não equivaler diretamente à quantidade de strings, se houverem espaços seguidos, mas se for o caso a quantidade de strings será inferior e por isso não fará muita diferença.

No fim do código a string foi quebrada para um array de strings, e por isso na posição `0` tem a primeira palavra, na posição `1` a segunda, e por ai em diante. Por isso o seu `str1` na pergunta equivale a `strings[0]`, o `str2` a `strings[1]`, etc.

### Quebra - Split com array alocado no *Heap*

Para complementar um pouco, mostro também um forma de quebrar utilizando o heap e respetivo `malloc`. Em muitos casos isto vai parecer mais natural pois pode ser agora feito tudo dentro de uma função e o array de strings resultante pode ser retornado. Como temos a função `realloc` deixa também de ser necessário contar inicialmente os espaços, pois dá para ir aumentando o array de strings cada vez que apanha uma nova.

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char** split(char *str, int *qtd){
    *qtd = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char **strings = NULL, *pch = strtok (str," ");
    while (pch != NULL){
        strings = realloc(strings, sizeof(char*) * (*qtd + 1));
        strings[i] = malloc(strlen(pch) + 1); // + 1 para o terminador
        strcpy(strings[i++], pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    return strings;
}

int main () {
    char str[] = "Bom dia pessoal";

    int qtd_strings, i;
    char **strings = split(str, &qtd_strings); //chamar o split e obter as strings
    for (i = 0;i < qtd_strings;++i){
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }

    //mostrar cada uma
    for (i = 0;i < qtd_strings;++i){
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }

    //ou seguindo o seu exemplo
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

[Veja também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/IYUoFK)

Repare que a função de quebra recebe um ponteiro para um inteiro chamado `qtd`. Isto acontece porque é preciso saber quantas strings foram criadas no `split`, caso contrário não as conseguimos utilizar. E como já existe o retorno do array de strings então não podia ser retornada a quantidade e a função troca o valor desse ponteiro diretamente.

Nesta versão sempre que não precisar mais das strings deve libera-las utilizando `free`, caso contrário poderá ter vazamentos de memoria.

Answer (score 0):

Estou assumindo que o cenário seria o mesmo do *exemplo*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){

    char str[] = "Bom dia pessoal";
    char *str1, *str2, *str3;
    str1 = strtok(str, " ");
    str2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    str3 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    printf("Primeira variavel: %s\nSegunda variavel: %s\nTerceira variavel: %s", str1, str2, str3);
    return 0;
}
```

Exemplo funcionando [Ideone](https://ideone.com/nEthhz)

Comment: Valeu cara! Funciona perfeitamente, mas por acaso teria como declarar um ponteiro de array? tipo char *str[40];